# How could I go the first Screen with Results flutter?

Tags: flutter

/*This is my code
On the main page:
*/

```
home: MyHomePage(),
  routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
    '/screen1': (BuildContext context) => new NewCreateProfile()
  },
```

// Want to come on this page with Results

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst );
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Define final variable in first screen use required
2. Set the value of results to a variable by setstate
3. Navigator.push( context,MaterialPageRoute(
           builder: (context) => firstscreen(result),
         ),
     );

Comment: I want to pop the page not push it

Comment: Do you want to pass the data to a dialog?? Or page ??